# How can i run my windows application on RaspberryPi2.?

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi2

Iam new to Raspberry Pi2, i have a windows application and a windows service which i wanted to run on Raspberry Pi2. I have windows 10 IOT installed on raspberry Pi2.

i had refereed to some sites that we need to install mono.if iam not wrong mono totally different again i need to write the whole code for mono, can any explain how can i run windows application and service which are compiled in X86 mode.

Any suggestion how can we install winodws 7 or windows 8 are alsoo helpful.